# Ajax: Manipulate input data prior to submitting form

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I am working on a website using Nodejs and Express. Being new to this area I encountered a problem that I have been already trying to fix for hours by now:

In an .html file I have a form containing an hidden input element and a button. The value of the hidden input element is empty and should be set right before the form gets sent (this should just emulate "manipulation of inputs" in this toy example). I would like to do this using Ajax. Here is my code:

For Ajax, I am including:

```
<script src="jquery.form.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/myAction" method="post" >
    <input value="" type="hidden" name="myInputName" id="myHiddenInput">
    <input type="button" value="Solve!" onclick="calculate()"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function calculate(){
    var myString = "test";
    document.getElementById('myHiddenInput').value = myString ;
    console.log("before ajaxForm");
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(res){
        console.log("middle ajaxForm");
        success: alert(res.toString());
        error: console.log("Something is wrong");;
    });
    console.log("after ajaxForm");
}
```

Nodejs:

```
app.post('/myAction', function (req, res) {
    console.log("Form arrived.");
    res.end();
})
```

However, my code doesn't seem to work.

**What I expect:**

- Client side: Console-Messages: "before ajaxForm", "middle ajaxForm", "after ajaxForm"
- Server side: Console-Message: "Form arrived."

**What I get:**

- Client side: Console-Messages: "before ajaxForm", "after ajaxForm"
- Server side: no console-message
- No errors at all

Has someone an idea what I may be doing wrong? Once something arrives at the server, how do I get access to the string "text" which is the value of the hidden input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function(){console.log("middle ajaxForm")},
    success: function(res){alert(res)},
    error: function(){console.log("Something is wrong")}
});
```

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm